# Why doesn't Python throw an error for slicing out of bounds?

Tags: python, slice

MATLAB throws an error for this:

```
>> a = [2,3,4]
>> a(3:4)

  index out of bounds
```

If something similar is tried with Python, why isn't it illegal?

```
>>> a = [2,3,4]
>>> a[2:3]
[4]
```

Isn't the Index '3' in python out of bounds, considering Numbering starts from Zero in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slicing never raise error in python for out of bound indexes..

```
>>> s =[1,2,3]
>>> s[-1000:1000]
[1, 2, 3]
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) on string(applies to lists, tuples as well):

> Degenerate slice indices are handled gracefully: an index that is too
>   large is replaced by the string size, an upper bound smaller than the
>   lower bound returns an empty string.

[Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)(lists):

> The slice of `s` from `i` to `j` is defined as the sequence of items with
>   index `k` such that `i <= k < j`. If `i` or `j` is greater than `len(s)`, use
>   `len(s)`. If `i` is omitted or `None`, use `0`. If `j` is omitted or `None`, use
>   `len(s)`. If `i` is greater than or equal to `j`, the slice is empty.

Out-of-range negative slice indices are truncated, but don’t try this for single-element (non-slice) indices:

```
>>> word = 'HelpA'
>>> word[-100:]
'HelpA'
```

Answer (score 1):

As others answered, Python generally doesn't raise an exception for out-of-range slices. However, and this is important, your slice is **not** out-of-range. Slicing is specified as a closed-open interval, where the beginning of the interval is inclusive, and the end point is exclusive.

In other words, `[2:3]` is a perfectly valid slice of a three-element list, that specifies a one-element interval, beginning with index 2 and ending just before index 3. If one-after-the-last endpoint such as 3 in your example were illegal, it would be impossible to include the last element of the list in the slice.

Answer (score 0):

You have a range there. As soon as one index from the range goes outside the bounds the process of extracting elements stops.

There are no errors in slicing in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Because `[2:3]` is from 4 to the next ele - 1, which returns 4.

Slicing never raises an error. The least it can do is return an empty list/tuple/string (depending on the type of course):

```
>>> a[12312312:]
[]
```

`[start:end:step]`

So index 2 is `4`, then `end - 1` is index 2 which is `4`.